# Script to add users to 'user and group' of a folder and give them Read and Write permissions, in Mac

Tags: macos, shell, unix, jenkins, file-permissions

Using Mac Yosemite 10.10.3

I have Jenkins installed on my mac which integrates with other applications and there is an important folder to which access should be present for all jenkins users. This can be achieved by adding them to its 'User and Group', and give them read, write access(Right click a folder/Get info/Sharing and permissions on bottom/that '+' symbol).

**My question in short :** To cut short, jenkins users should have access to that folder and should be present in 'User and Group' of that folder(Just as shown in the image below).

[image]

The above permission was given manually and I want to do that using a script which can be stored and invoked when needed.

(Am novice to shell scripting and to mac).

Comment: Together with a bounty, it would help to post some of your attempts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only the jenkins user need to access this folder with a R/W access, you can use the following commands:

```
sudo chown -R jenkins YOUR_FOLDER (set jenkins as the folder owner)
sudo chmod -R 755 YOUR_FOLDER (jenkins will have a R/W access, read for all the other users)
```

Update from June 16th 2015

This is a second solution to create a group build_users, add the jenkins user to this group and update the folder permissions.

```
-- Create the build_users group (with the ID 3333)
sudo dscl . -create /groups/build_users PrimaryGroupID 3333

-- Add the jenkins user in this group
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a jenkins -t user build_users

-- Make the group build_users owner of the folder
sudo chown -R :build_users my_folder

-- Give R/W permissions to the group build_users
sudo chmod -R g=rw my_folder
```

Comment: This is kind of close to what I need. When I ran above commands, it overwrote the actual owner of the folder, which was me(the one who logged into the system and created it). I don't want it to delete the original owner and his permissions, but to add to it. Like 2 owners who can read and write this folder. How to do that?

Comment: And one more question, does it apply these permissions to all sub-folders & files inside the folder to which we are applying these permissions?

Comment: The -R options apply the changes recursively. I'll try find a command to add an owner and keep the existing permissions :)

Comment: It's impossible to have two owners on file or folder in linux-based OS. A solution could be creating a group of users, put yourself and another user into that group and add group permissions (not user ones) on a files/folders.

Comment: So it should be groupadd - create new group and then useradd to it and then do whatever you have done above?

Comment: Yep you create a dedicated group, you add the relevant users (you, jenkins, ...) and you set some permissions using the group. Everything is my above answer (2nd answer).